# Why are CPU fans running on my MacBook Pro 15" full blast while my laptop has just booted up and waiting at the login screen?

Tags: macbook-pro, security, temperature

I know a lot of people have problems with the MacBook Pro's CPU fan running super loud and IMO the Activity Monitor is less than unreliable in telling what's really causing it… but let's check what happens when no applications are running.

What I find absolutely unbelievable that my Mac's CPU fans were running at maximum speed after just booting up, from a switched off state, with the charger cable disconnected. I can't see any reason for that, no applications should be running at this stage.

Is it possible to debug this somehow or is this simply an indication of a possible rootkit and a complete reinstall of my Mac?

[image]

Comment: Boot in safe mode (hold SHIFT until you see the Apple logo) if the problem goes away something that was installed is doing this. If the problem **doesn't** go away I would take it in for service.

Comment: How long after logging in did this occur?  Your machine could be running scripts.

Comment: Do you have access to a second Mac?  If I use Terminal's ⇧⌘K (Shell > New Remote Connection...) and connect via ssh, followed by running the top command (`top -o cpu`), I see mdsync using quite a bit of CPU percentage (not enough though to be problematic, some 20%). "Remote Login" in the "Sharing" System Preferences has to be enabled on the Mac with the issue.

Comment: @Redarm It's a very good idea to connect via SSH, I will try it, thanks! jmh: The fan speed went away I would say in a few minutes after logging in. Also this does not happen each time I start my mac, but occasionally it does.

Comment: @SteveChambers Unfortunately it behaves the same in safe mode, too. Redarm: I am not able to `ssh` nor `ping` the machine during login screen (as on my screenshot). Maybe it's due to FileVault but definitely no network until login.

Comment: Fans spin up because the SMC has detected from the various temp sensors that it reached a point where it needed to be cooled off.  Start with a reset of the SMC (this is one of the few instances where an SMC reset is relevant).  It's possible that you have errant processes using lots of CPU and/or you may have cooling issue like inefficient thermal paste on the heatsink or even dirty/blocked airflow resulting in inefficient cooling.  Start with the easy stuff like this first, and proceed from there.

Comment: @adamsfamily Yes FileVault changes things.  You could do an authenticated restart (`sudo fdesetup authrestart`), which would get you to the user login window and the ability to connect via ssh, but that would change the situation drastically and not reflect the current issue at all.

Comment: @Redarm Yes, I think the same. I have no idea what could be running on the MacBook before entering the password for the first time...

Comment: @adamsfamily Since there is little to no power management in EFI (before unlocking a FileVault disk), and no way of knowing how hot the Mac gets, there should be a fail-safe for just this case and if left sitting, your Mac should switch off after 5 minutes to help and make sure nothing overheats.  Is that not the case?

Comment: @adamsfamily PS. The main explanation I have heard about heat at the EFI login window was dust and particles in the MBP, but that's just hear say.

Comment: @Redarm Yes, dust etc. does build up inside the machine, and once there's enough to decrease the airflow reaching the heatsinks inside, then the fans have to spin faster to achieve the same amount of cooling.  (Eventually, even the maximum fan isn't enough to keep the CPU at a safe temperature when heavily loaded, and the CPUs will be throttled.  Also, the extra heat isn't good for the battery.  I speak from experience on all these points…)  However, it would have to be pretty severe to affect the login window — and symptoms would surely have been noticed before.  So I suspect something else.

Answer (score 0):

- Switch OFF FileVault drive encryption; or login after restarting/shutting down. (Tested)
- A clean install MAY help. (Haven't tested that)

Same problem with my '15 Macbook Pro with Monterey. This has started happening after a few recent macOS updates. I've read elsewhere it's something to do with a runaway FileVault system process.

Answer (score -1):

Check your login items and launch agents.
Update to the latest OS.
Open Activity Monitor when you log in. See what is gobbling up your CPU.

Comment: (I have the same comment as below) Are you sure that Login items can do anything before I first enter my password? Since I'm using FileVault, macOS should not be able to decrypt any of my files, it shouldn't know anything about Login items IMO.

Comment: I’m not a coder to give a definite answer, but some processes start up already when you press the ON button, so there is a chance some of them are preparing login items, etc. Login screen is just a visual interface, but Mac scripts run in the background. Not all processes have to have access to your data to run, imagine them as empty containers that are getting ready to be filled with your data when you login.

Comment: Besides, encryption prevents unauthorized users from accessing your data. I don’t think Mac prevents itself from running scripts on your data, at least not in all cases. There’s distinction between ‘accessing data’ (reading it) and ‘running scripts on data’ (moving it around without looking what’s inside).

Comment: This answer cannot be true, the FileVault login screen appears before macOS has booted since the disk is encrypted. This preboot is a separate read-only volume.